# window.dialogArguments is reset after postback in Firefox 3 showModalDialog function

Tags: javascript, firefox

The window.dialogArguments property is reset after a postback in Firefox 3. After a postback, and one attempts to set the window.dialogArguments property yields an error. On checking the property its value is undefined. This is weird since just when the modal window is opened the property seems to be created and can be accessed. This behaviour only happens after a postback. Is this a know bug with Firefox 3, since the method showModalDialog which is in IE since version 4 has just been implemented. How does one get around this?

Answer (score 2):

If the window.dialogArguments property is undefined, you can use the object directly via window.opener.myObject:

#### OPENER

```
m_oArgs = new Object;
m_oArgs.Foo = "";
window.showModalDialog("http://myUrl/dialog.aspx", m_oArgs, 'dialogWidth:350px;dialogHeight:140px;');
alert(m_oArgs.Foo)
```

#### DIALOG

```
var DA = window.dialogArguments;
if (DA != null) {
    DA.Foo = "MyArgument";
} else {
    if ((!window.opener.closed) && (window.opener.m_oArgs)) {
        window.opener.m_oArgs.Foo = "MyArgument";
    }
}
```